# Original AWSCognito framework not in newest AWS ios SDK

Tags: ios, swift, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk-ios

I inherited an iOS app that has `AWSCognito` as a dependency.

I'm receiving an error for `#import <AWSCognito/AWSCognito.h>` in a file.

Looks like this lib is needed to do the following

`AWSCognitoCredentialsProvider *credentialsProvider = [[AWSCognitoCredentialsProvider alloc]`

So looks like I just need some header to allow me to do that authentication. I tried grepping the sdk folder but haven't found that class in a header yet (references to it are everywhere and it's hard to find)

I downloaded the latest AWS ios SDK at [Latest iOS SDK](https://sdk-for-ios.amazonwebservices.com/aws-ios-sdk-2.22.1.zip)

I added a couple AWS frameworks by just dragging the `.xcframework` folders to `frameworks, libraries, etc`

Only thing is the `AWSCognito` framework is missing.

There's only `AWSCognitoAuth`, `AWSCognitoIdentityProvider`, and `AWSCognitoIdentityProviderASF`. Dragging all 3 of these over did not fix the error.

I downloaded an older version of the SDK that did have the `AWSCognito` folder (however, it was .framework and not .xcframework)...Regardless, I still got the same error.

Has the original `AWSCognito` framework been deprecated to a mixture of `AWSCognitoAuth`, `AWSCognitoIdentityProvider`, and `AWSCognitoIdentityProviderASF` ?

Do I just need to rename the import of the header file? Is there a version of the SDK that includes the original `AWSCognito.framework` as `.xcframework`.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I used `#import <AWSCognitoAuth/AWSCognitoAuth.h>` and that at least made the build pass.

I'm guessing this is just the newer lib to use and the regular `AWSCognito` is deprecated. Can anyone confirm?